# DT_WORDBREAK: list of word break symbols

Tags: winapi

I use DT_WORDBREAK flag when I call DrawTextEx. About this flag MSDN says:

> Lines are automatically broken between words if a word extends past
>   the edge of the rectangle specified by the lprc parameter. A carriage
>   return-line feed sequence also breaks the line.

But I cannot find "official" list of symbols that are used as word break symbols. Is it exist?

Comment: I think it's just whitespace characters (cr/lf/tab/space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the [TEXTMETRIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145132(v=vs.85).aspx)s for the font you're using, it corresponds to the tmBreakChar field.

For any Latin font, this is almost certainly just the plain old space character (Unicode `U+0020 SPACE` or ASCII 32).

I don't think DrawTextEx does anything fancier.  You'd have to use a more advanced API to get more sophisticated behavior such as breaking after hyphens, soft-hyphens, other kinds of spaces, etc.

Comment: "You'd have to use a more advanced API" - do you mean I have to create my own implementation? Or such API functions already exist.

Comment: "More advanced" may have been the wrong term.  Windows had Uniscribe that handles many of the details of rendering complex scripts, but it's a very low-level text rendering library that handles a lot of work to use it properly.  I don't recall if it has line breaking functionality baked in, but it would certainly make it possible to write your own.  If you're dealing strictly with left-to-right western scripts, you could write your own DrawText equivalent with custom word wrapping rules using GDI functions like ExtTextOut and GetTextExtent...